# How to setup autocomplete plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax, autocomplete

I have this code and I want to receive data from other server in jsonp format. But autocomplete is not showing any suggestions or errors? Here is plugins page https://goodies.pixabay.com/jquery/auto-complete/demo.html and my code

```
$(function(){
    $('#hero-demo').autoComplete({
        source: function(term, response){
            $.getJSON('http://178.62.17.188/players/jQueryCallback/ro', { q: term         }, function(data){ response(data); });
        },
        dataType: "jsonp"
    });
});
```

Comment: I checked plugin i think it not have source option.

Comment: This page is same for that plugin https://goodies.pixabay.com/jquery/auto-complete/demo.html . Here you see there says it supports jsonp . And I need it in dropdown not in alert

Comment: the source of two link that you send it not same. the second one have source option but the first one not have it.

Comment: So can you take a look at second one ？

Comment: could you please add your HTML code also?

Comment: first you dont have '#input' in your code. use this "#hero-demo"

Comment: yes, I just rename that for stackoverflow. I have change now. Still doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to provide more options it wasn't that simple. This now works like a charm.

```
  var xhr;
jQuery('.tableRow:last-child .tableTd').first().find('input').autoComplete({
    minChars: 2,
    jsonp: "callback",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    source: function(term, response){
          jQuery.ajax({
                    url: "http://api.someurl.com/players",
                    jsonp: "callback",
                    dataType: "jsonp",
                    data: {q: term, format: "json"},
                    success: function(data){response(data);}
        });
    },
    renderItem: function (item, search){
            // escape special characters
            if(!item.commonName == ""){
             return '<div class="autocomplete-suggestion" data-rating="'+ item.rating +'" data-cname="'+ item.commonName +'" data-val="'+search+'">'+ item.commonName + ' ('+ item.rating + ')' + '</div>';   
            }else{
             return '<div class="autocomplete-suggestion" data-rating="'+ item.rating +'" data-fname="'+item.firstName+'" data-lname="'+item.lastName+'" data-val="'+search+'">'+ item.firstName + ' ' + item.lastName + ' ('+ item.rating + ')' + '</div>';
                }
        },
    onSelect: function(e, term, item){
        if(!item.data('cname') == ""){
            jQuery('.tableRow:last-child .tableTd').first().find('input').val(item.data('cname'));
        }else{
            jQuery('.tableRow:last-child .tableTd').first().find('input').val(item.data('fname') + ' ' + item.data('lname'));
        }
        jQuery('.tableRow:last-child .tableTd').first().next().find('input').val(item.data('rating'));
    }
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Fetch data problem:

> Blocked loading mixed active content
>   "http://178.62.17.188/players/jQueryCallback/ro?q=t"

[Mixed Content](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Security/MixedContent)

[Test fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kq5d7j74/) (Console)

```
$('#hero-demo').autoComplete({
    minChars: 1,
    source: function(term, response){
            $.getJSON('http://178.62.17.188/players/jQueryCallback/ro', { q: term         }, function(data){
                response(data); });
        },
    dataType: "jsonp"
});
```

Edit 1:

> The best strategy to avoid mixed content blocking is to serve all the
>   content as HTTPS instead of HTTP.
>
> For your own domain, serve all content as HTTPS and fix your links. 
>   Often, the HTTPS version of the content already exists and this just
>   requires adding an "s" to links - http:// to https://.
>
> For other domains, use the site's HTTPS version if available. If HTTPS
>   is not available, you can try contacting the domain and asking them if
>   they can make the content available via HTTPS.

use `https://178.62.17.188/players/jQueryCallback/ro?jQueryCallback=?` instead of `http://178.62.17.188/players/jQueryCallback/ro`

Comment: goodies.pixabay.com/jquery/auto-complete/demo.html here you can take a look there is source option

Comment: link of repository in your question is : [link 1](https://github.com/devbridge/jQuery-Autocomplete) and link in your comment is [link 2](https://github.com/Pixabay/jQuery-autoComplete). **Two different libraries**

Comment: If you take a look from that pixabay page they are linking to that repo. Can you than take look at that second link that supports source？

Comment: no, that is data from other server. And I must transfer that data to my web site

Comment: @Bob Gaj, see my `Edit 1`.